# snappy-go can't decompress a string?

Tags: go, snappy

Code:

```
    stringReader := strings.NewReader(pbMsg.GetBody().GetReqData().GetContent())
    conBytes := make([]byte,1024)
    snappyReader := snappy.NewReader(stringReader)
    rNum, _ := snappyReader.Read(conBytes)
    fmt.Println("rNum", rNum)
```

I use the snappy-go in a `protobuf` project.The pb-string was compressed by snappy.

Now I want to to de-compress the string and get the pb-string, but when I use the `*string.Reader` as a parameter the `rNum` is `0`. Where's the error?

tips: `pbMsg.GetBody().GetReqData().GetContent()` returns a `string` (compressed by snappy).

thank you very much!!

Comment: Catch the Read error - if not nil what is it ?

Comment: readErr snappy: corrupt input

Comment: This is not enough code to really give a meaningful answer; you should provide a [mcve]. It looks like you're not compressing it correct or doing something else wrong.